# Why constant reference variables can't assign to reference variable but the function can?

Tags: c++

As the following program shows: when I tried to initialize a reference to int using a constant reference to int, the compiler consider it as an error. This is easy to understand because it prevent from potential modification of the right value.

However, I don't quite understand the logic behind the reason why I can assign a function who's return value is a constant reference.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
const string & version2(string & s1, const string & s2); // has side effect

int main()
{
    string input;
    string result;
    int a = 10;
    const int &c = a;
    int &d = c;  // warning here

    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    getline(cin, input);
    cout << "Your string as entered: " << input << endl;
    result = version2(input, "***");  // why no warning here?
    cout << "Your string enhanced: " << result << endl;

    std::cin.get();
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}


const string & version2(string & s1, const string & s2) // has side effect
{
    s1 = s2 + s1 + s2;
    // safe to return reference passed to function
    return s1;
}
```

Comment: Because a copy is made.

Comment: Those 2 examples aren't equivalent. `result` is not a reference, while `d` is. `int d = c;` doesn't throw a warning for the same reason, as why `result` doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of your function is a `const&`. The variable you are using in the `return` statement is a non-`const` variable.

There is nothing wrong with that. It's analogous to what you have in your posted code in `main`.

```
int a = 10;           // A non-const variable
const int &c = a;     // A const reference that references the non-const variable.
```

Regarding

```
result = version2(input, "***");  // why no warning here?
```

It's not wrong because you can initialize a non-`const` variable and assign to it using a `const&`.

Comment: Maybe it is more analogous to `int b=c`?

Comment: @buzhidao, exactly.